# How do I transfer an image texture from Geometry Nodes into Materials

Tags: materials, image, geometry-nodes

I have an Image Texture node in Geometry Nodes with an image in it that I also want to use with Shader Nodes

[image]

This is what I tried but it shows no image output, this is what it's meant to look like:

[image]

Is it possible to use an Image Texture inside Geometry Nodes as a texture for Materials? or to link these data-blocks somehow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it possible to use an Image Texture inside Geometry Nodes as a texture for Materials?

That'd be possible, I think what you're currently missing with your setup is the **Set Material** (and a **Subdivide Mesh**) node.

Also, an additional reminder. When your attribute is being outputted, it's nameless (or basically anonymous), which means that you can't tell Blender which attributes you'd want to be used. So, for an attribute to be usable in the Material Editor, you'd want to give the attribute a specified name (by typing in the blank space in the **Output Attributes** section in the Geometry Node modifier).
[image]

Once you're done with that, you can use that attribute in Material Editor.
[image]

The result:
[image]

The node setup:
[image]

Comment: You've been quicker with the answer... you should add, to get the attribute in the material it is necessary to name it in the Geometry Nodes modifier output and use that name as attribute. You do all this in your answer, but I could imagine it's not easy for a beginner to realize that from your explanation. The screenshot in the question for example looks like the attribute isn't named, it's just the default "Color" that comes from connecting the output.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, Gordon! I'll make adjustments to my answer according to your suggestions.

Comment: To be honest, when I was thinking about the answer I came to the conclusion that it is possible, but it would be so much easier if you just put an image texture in the material... but since that's not what is asked for... can't see a reason why I would want to do it through GN

Comment: And you'll need to add an ungodly amount of vertices to approach the same visual detail as a regular image texture in the shader editor. The question could be rephrased as "How can I bake an image texture to vertex colors in geometry nodes ?" because that's in essence what happens. Still, this answer is on point.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Yeah, I think the quicker way (or the usual way) of doing this is to put it directly in the Material editor. That would allow you to avoid putting it in one place (GN editor) and then you have to execute some supplementary steps just to move the result to another place (Material editor). But I'm sure that OP has some reasons to try this method instead :)

Comment: Surely, there must be a reason ;) But I'd really like to know why. I mean, the other thing is if you're also using a UV map on this texture coming from the original UVs of the original mesh and then put it back on the original mesh - what is the benefit of doing it in Geometry Nodes? I would be interested in which way this is advantageous.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann The reason I needed to use this method was for a special sort of rig that has lots of settings to customize, so I wanted to use Geometry Nodes as a way to save these custom settings as node groups then later use them as presets.

One of those settings is changing the image file, so I thought it would have been easier to somehow store the image inside GN in the same node group so that anyone who would want to put in their custom texture wouldnt need to like... put in their node group then change the image in materials, defeating the point of a preset

Comment: It's cool that it is possible though! but I guess it's really impractical since I would need to subdivide the mesh a ton to get the same result as plugging in the node in Materials instead. Thank you @CubicSpaceMonkN for helping me!

Comment: btw @CubicSpaceMonkN im curious, whats the reason that doing this requires a lot of vertices? wouldn't it just be able to use the UV map to apply the color on the face?

Comment: @Zophiekat: The main reason why it requires a lot of vertices (or geometry) it's because the attribute "UV map"  in GN editor has its values derived directly from each corner of the faces on your object. The more faces you have, the more face corners you'd have which would make the result become more accurate and clear. Here what those face corners look like, it sits somewhere close to your vertices' position https://imgur.com/a/KLiJlXE